# Warning: Undefined variable $localeFormatter in /var/core/www/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml on line 12

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5p1

I got this issue after upgrading Magento to the Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="blockVariables" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="secureRenderer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer\Proxy</item>
            <item name="escaper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Escaper</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

To

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="blockVariables" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="secureRenderer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer\Proxy</item>
            <item name="escaper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Escaper</item>
            <item name="localeFormatter" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Locale\LocaleFormatter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In app/etc/di.xml

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is working for me